# using NSPredicate in NSFetchedResultsController in core data

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have an app that uses core data and I am trying to generate filtered fetched results using NSPredicate. The model of my core data looks as following:

[image]

Essentially an author can have one or more quote. A tag can have many quote and vice versa and a Quote can belong to one or more pack (and hence a Pack can have one or more Quote).

So now I have been able to get all the quotes from an Author using the following:

```
self.fetchedResultsController = [Author MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:nil
                                                           withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"quotes.@count != 0"]
                                                                sortedBy:AuthorKeys.name
                                                               ascending:YES
                                                                delegate:self];
```

What if now I wanted to say give me all a list of Authors which has quotes in pack x,y, and z. How would I modify the NSPredicate above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should work.

```
NSArray *allowedPackNames = @[ @"x", @"y" ];
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"quotes.packs.packName IN %@", allowedPackNames];
```

Refer to the [Format String Summary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793-SW4)

Comment: @Phillipe shouldn't it be quotes.packs.packName?

Comment: @adit Pretty certain. Why not just try it?

Comment: in the syntax above, will it pull packName that is associated with X also it will pull up packName associated with Y? Or will it just look in any case where it matches?

Comment: @Phillipe I just tried it and now it gives me 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (quotes.packs.packName IN {"success", "happiness", "business"})'